# Install Brother HL-2300D on Ubuntu Server 16.10

Tags: printing, brother

Have Brother HL-2300D printer which I wanted to hook up to my server so that I can do wireless printing. I pulled down the driver from here:

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=hll2300d_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625

And was able to install it on my laptop running Mint with no problem. However, when I tried to install it on the server, I ran into a few issues and I thought I had worked through most of them.  I had to install lpr and cups since they weren't there so that I could run the installer.

After the installer runs, it tries to print a test page (running off usb, mind you):
lpr -P HLL2300D /usr/share/cups/data/testprint

The test print file definitely exists.  However the output of lpc status is:

> HLL2300D:
>   queuing is enabled
>   printing is enabled
>   cannot examine spool directory

Which is where I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran tasksel from apt-get to install print server.

```
sudo apt-get install print-server^
```

Then ran the [driver installer](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=hll2300d_us_eu_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) mentioned in the question.